# How to Deploy Django app with package django-private-chat

Tags: python, django, websocket

I am using [django-private-chat](https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat) in one of my application. it starts the chatserver on running command

> python manage.py run_chat_server

please help me deploying it on production server to run the chat server automatically.

i have tried adding the ChannelnameRouter class in routing.py of my project

1.

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            # path("notification_u/", UserNotificationConsumer),
        ])
    ),
    "chat-channel":MessageRouter(),

})
```

> 2. Creating Cron job for running the command automatically

Comment: Your question is quite broad and abstract. It all depends on how you want to deploy it, so first choose your deployment method, try something and then ask if you run into probems. FYI, the library you linked actually provided an example on how to deploy with systemd https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat/blob/dev/example.service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved, as the instructions to deploy it was already attached in the package.

Steps to solve the problem:-

> 1. sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/xyz.service

2.

```
Description=Django Private Chat example

After=network.target



[Service]

User=ubuntu

Environment="DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=************"

Environment="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=example.settings"

Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/example

ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/MyEnv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/example/manage.py run_chat_server

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> 3. sudo systemctl enable xyz